# Literature about optimal number of stocks in a diversified portfolio

Tags: equities, portfolio-management, portfolio, portfolio-selection, diversification

Is there any recent paper on how many assets one should consider for portfolio optimization techniques?

I found:

– https://www.jstor.org/stable/2330969?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents

– https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1540-6261.1981.tb00646.x

Comment: The expected Sharpe is [bounded](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.5936) by number of assets, true effect size, and length of history. The math here suggests a small number of degrees of freedom (probably less than 10) in any portfolio optimizer, but it depends on sample size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first article on this was Fisher and Lorie "Some studies of variability of returns on investments in common stocks" JB April 1970.
https://www.jstor.org/stable/2352105

The Statman article you quote "How many stocks make a diversified portfolio" is from 1987, it is still referenced and broadly agrees with the other.

A more recent article is Ronald Surz and Mitchell Price "Diversification by the Numbers" JOI 2000 which argues that more stocks may be needed than suggested by the earlier literature http://ppca-inc.com/Articles/DiversByNumbers.pdf

This is not a very active area of research AFAIK, I consider it a rather boring and settled issue.

Comment: I just found out from a friend that a literature review article on this topic was just published, with a long bibliography. Zaimovic, Omanovich and Arnaut are the authors. https://www.mdpi.com/1911-8074/14/11/551/htm It may interest you if you are looking for additional articles